# Swift - not getting the suggestion for the Variable name in println

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
var firstLoop = 0
for i in 2..<6 {
    firstLoop += i
}
println(firstLoop)
println("\(firstLoop)")
println("\(firstLoop.description)")
```

Here i am printing the `firstLoop` variable. But in the *first* `println`, when I type the word `firstLoop`, it is not showing any suggestions, while in next two `println` as I type `firstLoop` it is showing suggestions. Here can any one explain to me why it is not showing the suggestion in first `println`? And can I use this format to print the variable? Is that a correct way to print the varible?

Comment: Good use case. Please file a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is legal and correct; there is absolutely no need to perform string interpolation merely to `println` something (and indeed, string interpolation merely does the same thing `println` itself does, namely, calls the `description` of a Printable). You've found an Xcode code completion bug. This has nothing to do with iOS or Swift except tangentially; it's an Xcode problem.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a bug. Have you tried pressing the esc-key to show code suggestions?
For the second part of your question: In this case it doesn't really matter which println you use. The last two are essentially the same, since Swift automatically calls the description method of an object when you print it. However, for clarity's sake I would use this

```
println("firstLoop: \(firstLoop)")
```

to print the variable, just so you don't confuse it with another one you might print earlier or later in your code.

Comment: after your suggestion i used the esc-key but it is showing no completions and thanks for your answer.